# Why is Cloudflare not caching my images hosted on S3

Tags: image, amazon-s3, caching, cdn, cloudflare

I have tried everything and I am stumped so I will appreciate some help. I have an image on S3 with a cache-control of 'public, max-age=31536000'. The S3 is set up as a static website and I plan to serve it via Cloudflare. However, Cloudflare does not seem to cache the images. Here is an example URL:

https://media-dev.slpht.net/L32JrnoWRgD4xDYBuaEkYzpC

Inspecting it, I see

```
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
```

I think if it says DYNAMIC, that means that it is not caching. I am also getting 200 OK every time I refresh the page and I am expecting a 304?

Answer (score 1):

> Leaving the question and answering it in case it helps someone. If it does not, please remove this post.

It turns out that I have "Disable cache" on my Chrome browser on. When I turn it off, refreshing the page returns a 304.